# DirectX 12 Basic Compute Sample

Tags: c++, compute-shader, directx-12

**Duplicate**
[DirectX12 Compute Shader does nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67429198/directx12-compute-shader-does-nothing)

I tried BasicCompute11 sample by Mr.Chuck Walbourn.
https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/main/BasicCompute11

And I'm able to try out other compute functions like simple gaussian filter, median filter using DirectX 11.
Thank you very much @ChuckWalbourn for DirectX 11 compute sample.

And in DirectX 12, I'm unable to achieve simple addition also.

I tried to read most of the concepts and tried implementing. Compilation and Execution is successful but output is just zero values.

could anyone please provide basic compute sample in DirectX 12.
I looked at @ChuckWalbourn samples in this link
https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples

But it looks complex to understand for simple compute operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one sample in C language.
https://github.com/zenny-chen/Use-Direct3D-12-Compute-Shader-in-C-Basic-